# C++ , TCP Socket cannot receive data

Tags: c++, sockets

I created a BSD-POSIX TCP Socket class and now i have a problem.I have two wifi networks.One of them is an ADSL Router , and another one is hotspoted by an Android device.When i connect to ADSL Router wifi , i can't receive any data at all.The socket can send data , but there is no response.But when i connect to hotspoted wifi (Android device) , the program can receive data.I don't know what is the problem.Both WIFI Networks working fine.And also i used Wireshark to capture data.Data sent successful , but there is no receive.Here is my code:

```cpp
-------------------ESocket.cpp---------------------


#include "ESocket.h"
#include "stdio.h"

SOCKET s = NULL;


ESocket::ESocket(string ip,int port)
{
    struct sockaddr_in server;
    if((s = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0 )) == -1)
    {
        s = NULL;
    }
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ip.c_str());
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_port = htons( port );
    if (connect(s , (struct sockaddr *)&server , sizeof(server)) < 0)
    {
        s = NULL;
    }
}

ESocket::ESocket(SOCKET e)
{
    s = e;
}

ESocket::~ESocket()
{
    Destruct();
}



bool ESocket::isConnected()
{
    return (s != NULL);
}



int ESocket::Destruct()
{
  #ifdef _WIN32
    return WSACleanup();
  #else
    return 0;
  #endif
}



int ESocket::Close()
{


  int status = 0;
  #ifdef _WIN32
    status = shutdown(s, SD_BOTH);
    if (status == 0) { status = closesocket(s); }
  #else
    status = shutdown(s, SHUT_RDWR);
    if (status == 0) { status = close(s); }
  #endif

  return status;

}


bool ESocket::SendData(string data)
{

    if( send(s , data.c_str() , data.length() , 0) < 0)
    {
        s = NULL;
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}


string ESocket::ReceiveData(int len)
{
    int recv_size;
    char reply[len];
    if((recv_size = recv(s , reply , len , 0)) < 0)
    {
        return "";
    }

    if (recv_size == 0)
    {
        s = NULL;
        return "";
    }
    printf("%i",recv_size);
    reply[recv_size] = '\0';
    return reply;
}





int ESocket::setAsNonBlock()
{

    int res;
    #ifdef _WIN32
    u_long iMode = 1;
    res = ioctlsocket(s, FIONBIO, &iMode);
    #else
    int opts;
    opts = fcntl(s, F_GETFL);
    if(opts < 0)
    {
        res = -1;
    }
    opts = (opts | O_NONBLOCK);
    if(fcntl(s, F_SETFL, opts) < 0)
    {
        res = -1;
    }
    #endif
    return res;
}









-------------------ESocket.h---------------------


#ifndef ESOCKET_H
#define ESOCKET_H

#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

#ifdef _WIN32
  #ifndef _WIN32_WINNT
    #define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0501
  #endif
  #include <winsock2.h>
#else
typedef int SOCKET;
  #include <sys/socket.h>
  #include <arpa/inet.h>
  #include <netdb.h>
  #include <unistd.h>
  #include <fcntl.h>
#endif

class ESocket
{
    public:
        ESocket(string ip,int port);
        ESocket(SOCKET e);
        virtual ~ESocket();
        int Destruct();
        int Close();
        int setAsNonBlock();
        bool SendData(string data);
        bool isConnected();

        string ReceiveData(int len);

static int Init()
{
  #ifdef _WIN32
    WSADATA wsa_data;
    return WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(1,1), &wsa_data);
  #else
    return 0;
  #endif
}

    static string getIP(char* host)
    {

    struct hostent *he;
    struct in_addr **addr_list;

    char ip[100];


    int i;

    if ( (he = gethostbyname( host ) ) == NULL)
    {
        return "";
    }

    addr_list = (struct in_addr **) he->h_addr_list;

    for(i = 0; addr_list[i] != NULL; i++)
    {

        strcpy(ip , inet_ntoa(*addr_list[i]) );
    }
    string x = ip;
    return x;
    }


    protected:

    private:

};

#endif // ESOCKET_H








------------------------MAIN-----------------------
ESocket::Init();
ESocket e(ESocket::getIP("www.google.com").c_str(),80);
if (e.isConnected())
{
     cout<<e.SendData("GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.google.com\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\n\r\n");
}
else
{
    printf("Not connected");
    return 0;
}

while (e.isConnected()){
cout<<e.ReceiveData(100);
}
printf("\nEND OF CONNECTION");
```

EDIT: Solved by reset wifi router.

Comment: First, you don't have a legal HTTP 1.1 request. If nothing else, the `Host` header is missing. Second, how much data you receive is arbitrary, since you only call `recv` once.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I used a while loop , no response.i tried so many other hosts , too.it sticks in cout<<e.ReceiveData(100); because it is not non-block.

Comment: Your `main` doesn't set the socket non-blocking. If you do, your code will break horribly. *Don't do that!*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several serious bugs:

1. Your receive function has no code to support the "would block" condition and so it will not work reliably with non-blocking sockets.
2. Your receive function provides no reliable way to tell whether it got an error or not (as opposed to an empty string). It corrupts the socket value on an error, so calling it again after an error is potentially disastrous. Yet it provides no way at all to avoid this.
3. You set the socket to `NULL`. But nothing makes `NULL` an invalid value for a socket. On WIN32, use `INVALID_SOCKET`. On other platforms, use -1.

You also have a more minor issue. Your request claims HTTP 1.1 compliance, but it is not an HTTP 1.1 compliant request. For example, HTTP 1.1 makes "Host" headers mandatory. Don't claim compliance with a protocol you have no intention of supporting. What happens if you get back a reply that uses chunked encoding?
Likely what's happening is that receive is encountering a "would block" condition, corrupting the socket, and then you call receive again with an invalid socket which, of course, fails.

Comment: None of the above is my problem.This http request works fine on google.com , you can test it.And also to ensure , i added "Host: www.google.com" but there is no receive.For avoiding errors , i used s= NULL; , and by using while(ESocket.isConnected()) , we can be sure about the connection.because it checks (s != null).

Comment: I am 99% sure that 1 is your problem. Modify your receive function to correctly support a "would block" indication and your problem will go away.

Comment: Also, why does the code you gave us bear no resemblance to the code that actually has the error?! That makes answering very frustrating. You don't show any such while loop. You don't show any call to the function to set the socket non blocking. :/

Comment: Can you please show me a code or edit my code for "correctly support a "would block" indication" ? @DavidSchwartz

Comment: @MHzCode Honestly, I would say just don't use your receive function. It provides no way to distinguish between an error and receiving an empty string. And don't set the socket to `NULL`. A socket isn't a pointer, and a `NULL` will likely be treated as zero, which on UNIX systems is a valid descriptor.

Comment: Does it work if you don't set the socket non-blocking? Can you show us the actual code you are using?

Comment: No it doesn't work in non-blocking mode.I don't think that this is a code problem.I see other questions about this problem , too.Maybe it is a network problem on wifi router? i edited my main() in post.please review it.

Comment: Does it work if you *don't* set the socket non-blocking?

Comment: No it doesn't work at all.It only Connects to target server , sends the data , and in the end there is no response.i checked it on wireshark , too.

Comment: Your code still doesn't send a valid HTTP 1.1 request, since it has two line endings in the middle of the header. Could you fix all the obviously broken stuff and then update your question to show your *real* code?

Comment: Trust me man! this is not the problem! if it is the main problem , at least , the server should send "http bad request".Wait i should edit the code to be ensure about that "this is not the code problem"

Comment: @MHzCode I believe David is asking you if it works in **blocking mode**. I'm just trying to make sure the double negation (**don't** set **non-blocking**) isn't causing any confusion and that you are answering the question they are asking.

Comment: The problem is solved by reseting wifi router.I don't know why! :|

Comment: I hope you won't use that as an excuse not to fix the bugs in your code.

Comment: Thanks for your help david!